# The diagonal representation of Pauli $y$ matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

The textbook says the eigenvalue of the Pauli y matrix is 1 and -1, the corresponding eigenvectors are,

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
i
\end{bmatrix}
, \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-i
\end{bmatrix}
 $$

But it seems I cannot get the original Pauli y matrix by adding the outer product representation, also, these two eigenvectors are supposed to be orthogonal, but it seems that they are not. So where did I do wrong?

Comment: Be reminded that you need to take the complex conjugate of one of the vectors in the inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\psi_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{bmatrix}$ and $\psi_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{bmatrix}$ you get
$$ \psi_1 \psi_1^\dagger = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
and
$$ \psi_2 \psi_2^\dagger = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$
Then
$$ (1) \cdot \psi_1 \psi_1^\dagger + (-1) \cdot \psi_2 \psi_2^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \sigma_y. $$

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

They seem orthogonal: $\psi_2^\dagger \psi_1=0$.

Comment: Thank you, but by calculating the outer product representation I can't get the original pauli y matrix. Did I do it in the wrong way?

Comment: @Pierce : I don't know what you're talking about. Why the outer product should equal the Pauli matrix? The rank of the outer product is one, unlike that of the Pauli matrix.

Comment: Right, I guess I'm not saying it clearly, but thank you anyway.